# setInterval setting this to window instead of class (calling class function)

Tags: javascript, class, this, setinterval

```
render() {
    drawRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height,3);
    console.log(this) // when called with setInterval(classObject.render, 1000), returns window; if called with (classObject).render returns (classObject)
    for (let i = 0; i <= this.sprites.length; i++) {
        if (this.sprites[i]) {
            let cs = this.sprites[i]
            cs.drawRoutine(cs.position.x,cs.position.y);
        }
    }
}
setRenderInterval(fps) {
    setInterval(this.render,1000/fps);
}
```

Here, let's assume `classObject` is called `game`.
When `game.render()` is called normally, it has `game` as `this`. But when it's called using setInterval, it has `window` as `this`. How can I circumvent this?
`this.sprites` is an array of sprites for the game, and it needs to be accessed using this, as there can be multiple games with different variable names. And cs.drawRoutine is a function within the sprite that just draws in the canvas. The function runs when normally called.

As requested (and because this is going to be open source later), here's the whole class and the thing that calls it:

```
class gameController extends instance {
constructor(name="untitled") {
    super(name);
    this.camera = null;
    this.rendering = {"FPS":0,"cnv":null,"ctx":null}
    this.sprites = [];
    this.data.renderFrame = 0;
}
render() {
    drawRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height,3);
    for (let i = 0; i <= this.sprites.length; i++) {
        if (this.sprites[i]) {
            let cs = this.sprites[i]
            cs.drawRoutine(cs.position.x,cs.position.y);
        }
    }
}
setRenderInterval(fps) {
    return setInterval(this.render,1000/fps);
}

}

const game = new gameController("game");
game.setRenderInterval(30); // called from script/devconsole
```

Comment: Could you please share a larger code snippet for clarity? Your whole class object perhaps and the scope of the setRenderInterval function would be nice!

Comment: `setInterval(() => this.render(), 1000/fps)`

Comment: @PéterSzabó-tóth I added the class and the scope; thanks for pointing that out!